# Is there an easy way to select across rows in a panda frame to create a new column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

*Question updated, see below*

I have a large dataframe similar in structure to e.g.

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 0, 11, 22,33], 'B': [10, 20,30, 110, 220, 330], 'C':['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z']})
df
```

```
    A   B   C
0   0   10  x
1   0   20  y
2   0   30  z
3   11  110 x
4   22  220 y
5   33  330 z
```

I want to create a new column by selecting the column value of B from a different row based on the value of C being equal to the current row and the value of A being 0, so the expected result is

```
    A   B   C   new_B_based_on_A_and_C
0   0   10  x   10
1   0   20  y   20
2   0   30  z   30
3   11  110 x   10
4   22  220 y   20
5   33  330 z   30
```

I want to have a simple solution without needing to have a for loop over the rows. Something like

```py
df.apply(lambda row: df[df[(df['C']==row.C) & (df['A']==0)]]['B'].iloc[0], axis=1)
```

The dataframe is guaranteed to have those values and the values are unique

---

**Update for a more general case**
I am looking for a general solution that would also work for multiple columns to match on e.g.

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 0,0, 11, 22,33, 44], 'B': [10, 20,30, 40, 110, 220, 330, 440], 'C':['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], 'D': [1, 1, 5, 5, 1,1 ,5, 5]})
```

```
A   B   C   D
0   0   10  x   1
1   0   20  y   1
2   0   30  x   5
3   0   40  y   5
4   11  110 x   1
5   22  220 y   1
6   33  330 x   5
7   44  440 y   5
```

and the result would be then

```
A   B   C   D   new_B_based_on_A_C_D
0   0   10  x   1   10
1   0   20  y   1   20
2   0   30  x   5   30
3   0   40  y   5   40
4   11  110 x   1   10
5   22  220 y   1   20
6   33  330 x   5   30
7   44  440 y   5   40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question, for the general case you could use a merge like this:

```
df.merge(df.loc[df['A'] == 0, ['B', 'C', 'D']], on=['C', 'D'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_new'))
```

Output:

```
A   B   C   D   B_new
0   10  x   1   10
0   20  y   1   20
0   30  x   5   30
0   40  y   5   40
11  110 x   1   10
22  220 y   1   20
33  330 x   5   30
44  440 y   5   40
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do a map:

```
# you **must** make sure that for each unique `C` value, 
# there is only one row with `A==0`.
df['new'] = df['C'].map(df.loc[df['A']==0].set_index('C')['B'])
```

Output:

```
    A    B  C  new
0   0   10  x   10
1   0   20  y   20
2   0   30  z   30
3  11  110  x   10
4  22  220  y   20
5  33  330  z   30
```

**Explanation**: Imagine you have a series `s` indicating the mapping:

```
idx 
idx1  value1
idx2  value2
idx3  value3
```

then that's what map does: `df['C'].map(s)`.

Now, for a dataframe `d`:

```
C  B
c1 b1
c2 b2
c3 b3
```

we do `s=d.set_index('C')['B']` to get the above form.

Finally, as mentioned, you mapping happens where `A==0`, so `d = df[df['A']==0]`.

Composing the forward path:

```
mapping_data = df[df['A']==0]
mapping_series = mapping_data.set_index('C')['B']
new_values = df['C'].map(mapping_series)
```

and the first piece of code is just all these lines combined.

Comment: is there a way to make this work for multiple `C` columns to match? I can update my question to reflect that specific case better. thanks!

Comment: Looks really efficient! Any chance you could break down how this works a bit more?

Comment: @CallumDA see if the updated answer helps.

Comment: Thank you! If only I could upvote twice.. much appreciated